# Pan fried chicken taste like pan?

Tags: chicken, pan, frying-pan

I just got some canned chicken and fried it with a little water I.e. pan fried without oil and just adding little bits of water as I go.

The chicken tasted like the metal pan itself if you know what I mean?  Why did this happen and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Did it taste like the pan, or like the can?  There are a lot of people who say that canned food tastes metallic

Comment: Pan frying with water?

Comment: @Joe it was the definately the pan.  I have fried in oil as well as grilled etc but the chicken. Didn’t taste like a pan presumably since I didn’t use one.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes.  I tried to fry without oil and online searches said add a teaspoon of water to prevent drying as you go and you should be able to cook it without oil.

Comment: maybe canned chicken is just a bad product to eat (flavour, taste, texture...)

Comment: When have you eaten pan to know what it tastes like @JamesWilson?

Comment: @GdD lol.  Just tastes metallic but when I have used oil, grill etc this does not occur.

Comment: It can be avoided by throwing the canned chicken in the garbage where it belongs.

Comment: @eps why is there so much hate on canned meat on this board. I guess that could be a seperate question.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that's what going on is this:

- There is an metallic flavor in the canned meat
- Browning the meat either reduces that flavor, or masks it with other flavors

Steaming, poaching, or other water-based cooking method isn't going to allow it to come to a sufficient temperature to brown it.  Grilling or frying (in oil) will cause the Maillard reaction (protein browning) which creates new chemical compounds.

If you have a microwave, try heating up a slice in there, as I suspect that it'll still taste metallic.  If you don't have a microwave, you could try steaming it, or just sampling it at room temperature.